# Close button for AdMob banner

Tags: android, admob

Is there any way to set a close button at a AdMob's banner? I mean those small 'x' to dismiss the banner...

I'm currently adding my banner to the layout like this:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="my_id_here"
        ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
```

Comment: it is possible, just use a relativelayout to position the 'x' button and set an onclicklistener on it to hide the adview. I would double check to see if this is ok with Admobs terms and conditions though

Comment: @KennyC, thanks for the answer. In fact, the way you explained I already knew it could be done... I wished to know if there is a default (reliable/admob recommended) form to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to include an X button on a banner ad using the SDK. Hopefully this feature becomes available sometime down the road.